# MySQL - Optimize Queries Runtime

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with the [`tpch` database](https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/assets/img/datasets-generated/tpch.svg) and have a query that I want to optimize with faster runtimes.

I tried adding indexes and views to the query, but they are not improving performance. Could someone please provide suggestions? Thanks.

---

**Connection:**

```
conn = mysql.connect(host = 'relational.fit.cvut.cz', port = int(3306), user = 'guest', passwd = 'relational', db = 'tpch')
```

**Query:**

```
WITH customer_lifetime_value AS (
  SELECT
    c_custkey,
    c_name,
    c_address,
    c_nationkey,
    c_phone,
    c_acctbal,
    c_mktsegment,
    c_comment,
    SUM(o_totalprice) AS ltv
  FROM customer
  JOIN orders
    ON o_custkey = c_custkey
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
)

SELECT
  r_name,
  MAX(ltv) AS best_customer_value
FROM region
JOIN nation
  ON n_regionkey = r_regionkey
JOIN customer_lifetime_value clv
  ON clv.c_nationkey = n_nationkey
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this? It should read less data and give you the same output:

```
WITH customer_lifetime_value AS 
(
    SELECT o_custkey
          ,SUM(o_totalprice) AS ltv
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY o_custkey
)
SELECT
  r_name,
  MAX(ltv) AS best_customer_value
FROM customer_lifetime_value
JOIN customer
    ON o_custkey = c_custkey
JOIN nation
    ON c_nationkey = n_nationkey
JOIN region
    ON n_regionkey = r_regionkey
GROUP BY r_name
```

If it is correct, you can create simple indexes:

- on orders table including only the o_custkey and o_totalprice
- on customer table including only c_custkey and c_nationkey

Comment: Seems like it would be better to do `GROUP BY r_name` _before_ `JOINing` to the other 3 tables??