# MySQL - Optimize Query Runtime

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with the [`tpch` database](https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/assets/img/datasets-generated/tpch.svg) and have a query that I want to optimize for faster runtime.

I tried adding indexes to `li.l_orderkey`, `o.o_custkey`, and `c.c_mktsegment`, but they are not improving performance. Could someone please provide suggestions? Thanks.

---

**Connection:**

```
conn = mysql.connect(host = 'relational.fit.cvut.cz', port = int(3306), user = 'guest', passwd = 'relational', db = 'tpch')
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
  c.c_mktsegment,
  COUNT(o.o_orderkey) AS num_orders,
  SUM(li.l_quantity) AS total_quantity,
  SUM(li.l_extendedprice) AS total_price
FROM lineitem li
JOIN orders o
  ON li.l_orderkey = o.o_orderkey
JOIN customer c
  ON o.o_custkey = c.c_custkey
WHERE li.l_commitdate BETWEEN '1997-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND '1997-12-31T00:00:00Z'
GROUP BY c.c_mktsegment;
```

Comment: Asking about the query performance you must provide: complete CREATE TABLE for all tables; query text; data statistic (total rows, matched rows, output rows); query execution plan. At least..

Comment: I would guess your query needs to read a significant amount of data (a whole year). If you are running it at night, it's OK for a batch process to be slow. Such a query may not suitable as an online query for immediate responses, though.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75443947/mysql-optimize-queries-runtime ?

Comment: Remember that `JOINs` are done before "aggregation".  I would expect that count and those sums to be bigger than they should be.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a query to use a specific index, it should be covering - including all columns in the query. Your `lineitem` items seems to have a lot of records, so the most of the data is read there.

You can try creating index on `lineitem` table with the following columns:

- l_commitdate
- l_orderkey
- l_quantity
- l_extendedprice

The idea is to reduce the read columns count (data row size) and to be able to filter by `l_commitdate`.

Another approach will be pre-calculating this information using trigger or the routine which is adding/updating/deleting the line items records, but it will be more complex.